# why do MySQL displays the same column twice?

Tags: php, mysql, database

Hello every ***{body]*** !
I have a simple "members" table to which I normally add rows with the function bellow.
[image: MySQL table "members"]

[image: Function adding a member]

The problem is that when I call the read function, it returns each column to me twice. Like this:

[image: Read result]

The weirdest thing is that all the columns are correct except "phone", it returns me '1' instead of an empty string.

Can anybody help me please ?

Here is the read function:

```
function db_read($columnToRead, $table, $targetColumn, $targetValue) {

    //connecting to database
    include('dbConnection.php');
    
    //reading data
    $result = $tilelli->prepare('SELECT '.$columnToRead.' FROM '.$table.' WHERE '.$targetColumn.' = ? LIMIT 1');
    if ($result->execute(array($targetValue))) {
        return $result->fetch();
    } else {
        return "Accès à la base de données refusé!";
    }
}
```

And here is the calling method:

```
//reading member
$member = db_read("*", "members", "link", $_SESSION["member"]["link"]);
print_r($member);
exit;
```

Comment: Grab results only as associative, or as indexed... not both. "*PDO::FETCH_BOTH (default): returns an array indexed by both column name and 0-indexed column number as returned in your result set*" https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Comment: (your code is heaven for sql-injection. i´m pretty sure even php is able to prepare/parameter-bind). string-concat + unhashed password. nice combination

Comment: @IncredibleHat Thank you bro, you enlightened me on the first "problem", but it remains the weirdest: Why do the "phone" column returns 1 instead of an empty string ?

Comment: @MichaelHauptmann I know my friend, I am in the development phase, I'll adjust the security issues later...

Comment: what do you mean 'phone' column return 1 instead of empty string? what I can see from your image, phone has value of '0557190308' as string

Comment: @BoykeFerdinandes Look at the response bellow bro...

Answer (score 0):

@BoykeFerdinandes

Yes, when I print_r($member), it displays the phone correctly, but look at the web page :

[PHP code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKGHo.jpg)

[HTML result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s245a.jpg)

Here is the "info()" function:

```
//inserting a profile info
function info($svg, $text, $buttonHref, $buttonLabel, $rounded = false, $previewable = false, $notif = "") {
    $style = "";
    $class = "";
    $notification = '<span class="notifCounter">'.$notif.'</span>';
    if ($rounded)
        $style = 'style="border-radius: 50%;"';
    if ($previewable)
        $class = ' previewable';
    echo    '<div class="info">
                <p class="info_icon_container">
                    <img src="'.$svg.'" class="info_icon'.$class.'" '.$style.' />
                </p>
                <p class="info_text">
                    '.$text.'
                </p>
                <p class="info_alter" onclick="window.location=\''.$buttonHref.'\';">
                    '.$buttonLabel.$notification.'
                </p>
            </div>';
}
```

Comment: in your php code, what is the result of `$member["phone"]`, is it 1? or is it '0557190308' ? and I havent used php for a while, can you try using `!=`? Im not sure if `=!` does the same thing as `!=`

Comment: @BoykeFerdinandes Ooh la la! It's a simple typo: I put (=!) Instead of (!=)
Thank you my friend, you pointed it out to me.

Comment: glad to be a help.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry friends, this is a stupid typo. I put (=!) Instead of (!=) In the php code.

```
$phone = "Aucun numéro de téléphone";
if ($member["phone"] =! "")
    $phone = $member["phone"];
```